# how to covert this string in 10 different nodes in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

My String is =

```
[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1]
```

How to convert it into 10 different nodes/values? My current attempt is like this

```
select  CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE('[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1]', '[', ''), ']', ''),',',''),' ','</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS Data
```

Answer=

```
<A>10</A><A>17</A><A>315</A><A>410</A><A>114</A><A>1</A>
```

I want it in 10 nodes/values instead of above. How i should do it in sql server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for comments

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@data, '],[', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')
```

Result :

```
10, 17, 315, 410, 114, 1
```

**EDIT :**

Is seems to you are looking for values only

```
select LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)'), '[', ''), ']', '')) [Data] from
(
    select  CAST('<A>'+REPLACE('[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1]', ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS xml) AS Data 
)a cross apply Data.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
```

Result :

```
Data
10
1
7
3
15
4
10
1
14
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Already provided answers seem to work well, but I thought about a more versatile one (may work in more complex scenarios) using regular expressions:

1. Install [sql-server-regex](https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex) (e.g. [for Sql Server 2014](https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex/blob/master/install/sql-2014.md))
2. Use a "split" method

   ```
   select Match from dbo.RegexSplit(@data, '\D') where Match <> ''
   ```

Performance testing

I noticed that using CLR functions is **much faster** than REPLACE as indicated below:

1. Using `RegexSplit` (**about 20s for 1M elements**)

   ```
   declare @baseMsg varchar(max) = '[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1],' 
   declare @data varchar(max) = replicate(@baseMsg, 1000000)
   select Match from dbo.RegexSplit(@data, '\D') where Match <> ''
   ```
2. Using `REPLACE` (**about 15s for 2K elements**)

   ```
   declare @baseMsg varchar(max) = '[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1],' 
   declare @data varchar(max) = replicate(@baseMsg, 200)

   select LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)'), '[', ''), ']', '')) [Data] from
   (
       select  CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(@data, ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS xml) AS Data 
   )a cross apply Data.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
   ```

So, we are talking about a difference of three orders of magnitude.

Of course, the solution should be chosen based on string length ,security permissions (maybe the SQLCLR is not allowed or the external library must be analyzed before it is allowed to run within SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, SQL should be as below :

```
select  CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(
      REPLACE('[10, 1],[7, 3],[15, 4],[10, 1],[14, 1]', '[', ''),
       ']', ' '),
    ',',''),
  ' ','</A><A>') +'</A>' AS XML) AS Data
```

Comment: It was before to your answer..Any way Thanks